# Why does GetWindowThreadProcessId return 0 when called from a service?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

When using the following class in a console application, and having at least one instance of Notepad running, `GetWindowThreadProcessId` correctly returns a non-zero thread id.  However, if the same code is included in a  Windows Service, `GetWindowThreadProcessId` always returns `0` and no exceptions are thrown.  Changing the user the service launches under to be the same as the one running the console application didn't alter the result.  What causes `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to return `0` even if it is provided with a valid hwnd?  And why does it function differently in the console application and the service?  Note: I am running Windows 7 32-bit and targeting .NET 3.5.

```
public class TestClass
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

    public void AttachToNotepad()
    {
        var processesToAttachTo = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad")

        foreach (var process in processesToAttachTo)
        {
            var threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(process.MainWindowHandle, 
                IntPtr.Zero);

            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Console Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testClass = new TestClass();

        testClass.AttachToNotepad();
    }
}
```

Service Code:

```
public class TestService : ServiceBase
{
    private TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new TestService());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        testClass.AttachToNotepad();

        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A service runs in its own session, the infamous session 0 in Vista and Win7.  That session isolates services from the user desktop, it runs in another session.  Specifically to prevent a service that usually runs with a very privileged account (like LocalSystem) from interacting with the user.  A security hole.

Accordingly, a service cannot see the window handles owned by another session.

Not sure why you are doing this but you typically need a helper program that presents a user interface and communicates with the service through an IPC mechanism like named pipes, sockets, .NET remoting or WCF.  If you use a named pipe, prefix the pipe name with `"Global\"` so all sessions can see it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  On further review, its probably a better design decision to run my code in an application instead of a service.

Answer (score 1):

You could also enable the option "Allow service to interact with desktop" and see if that works.  Otherwise I would have to agree with onbugz comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that before posting and it didn't seem to affect my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Service has no UI, so it has no window.

Comment: But I'm querying the thread ID of an instance of notepad.exe, not the service itself.