# Why does GetWindowThreadProcessId return 0 when called from w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, excel-2010

When running the following code, `GetWindowThreadProcessId` returns 0. I've read about [the same problem happening with a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461171/why-does-getwindowthreadprocessid-return-0-when-called-from-a-service), but this code is being run as an Application Pool in IIS (namely, w3wp.exe). Also, both w3wp.exe and the EXCEL.EXE it is trying to kill are running in the same session (session 0), and as the same user.

```
if (appClassXls != null)
{
    IntPtr processId = default(IntPtr);
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(appClassXls.Hwnd, out processId);
    Process processXls = Process.GetProcessById(processId.ToInt32());
    if (processXls != null)
    {
        processXls.Kill();
    }
}
```

Obviously this code fails since it will try to kill pid 0 which is the System Idle Process instead of the Excel Application instance it's trying to kill. Why would `GetWindowThreadProcessId` return 0 when called from w3wp.exe in the same session as the same user? And how do I make it return the correct pid?

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (64 bit)
IIS 7.5
.NET Framework v4.0
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 (clean install, set to launch as specific user in DCOM setting, launched by w3wp.exe)

UPDATE (2011-02-17 08:33 UTC):
I just realized that w3wp.exe is launched by "svchost.exe -k iissvcs" which corresponds to the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and the "Windows Process Activation Service" and EXCEL.EXE is launched by "svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch" which corresponds to "DCOM Server Process Launcher", all 3 of which are services. Both of the svchost.exe's are running as SYSTEM in session 0 though, so I still don't see why they or their children would have trouble accessing each other.

Comment: I can't see why this would work given that the processes you are trying to kill are headless.

Comment: Can you see what appClassXls.Hwnd is?

Comment: Does GetWindowThreadProcessId return a valid thread id? If not, maybe there's something fishy going with appClassXls.Hwnd

Comment: @OJ why wouldn't killing a headless process work?

Comment: @OJ, Winston, & Ken: The exact same code works on other machines with the same OS, so the logic should be fine. It's more likely a configuration issue.

Comment: @Winston appClassXls.Hwnd is 131802... it looks valid. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ken GetWindowThreadProcessId is putting 0 in processId

Comment: What does the GetWindowThreadProcessID actually return (not the out parameter)

Answer (score 1):

See this [blog entry](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx) which explains how Session 0 isolation works. It looks like services and applications cannot talk to each other. I am trying to figure out how "session 0" is assigned. I believe the window station w3wp is assigned to is not the same as the one for the excel (I assume) it launched.

I recommend avoiding launching excel from a web application. You can easily hang the server doing that. I remember several issues due to reference count leaks on the excel causing memory issues that would ultimately lead to the server's demise. :)

Comment: Yes, you assume correctly that w3wp launched excel. However, they should be sharing the same window station if "Each session is associated with its own interactive window station" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and both w3wp.exe and EXCEL.EXE are in session 0. Also, w3wp.exe is not a service, is it? Do services have anything to do with my problem? P.S. thanks for the recommendation, I'm aware of the risks of launching excel from a web app and that Microsoft doesn't support it. Unfortunately it's the best option for me right now. duly noted though =)

Comment: Are you getting the window handle correctly on the system? It might be a privileges issue if it works in other machines.

Comment: appClassXls.Hwnd is 131802... it looks valid. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, the launching user is a full blown Administrator with UAC turned off, so I'm clueless as to what the privilege issue might be

Comment: Is w3wp running as the same user (i.e. did you change the user from Network service for the app pool to be a specific user?) and is excel.exe set to run under the privileges of the "launching user"? Just making sure that these are valid. If those are correct, Can you use a different method (GetProcessByName) and see if you get a different result.  I apologize if you have tried these. :)

Comment: Yes, w3wp is running as Administrator, and Excel is running under the privileges of the "launching user", which is Administrator. I'll try GetProcessByName and see what I get.