# Why always return 0 when Get PID in C# with IIS? But run with ASP.NET Develop Server is normal

Tags: c#, excel, pid

#### Why always **return 0** when Get PID in C# **with IIS**? But run with **ASP.NET Develop Server is normal.**

CODE：

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace MyWeb
{
    public class SWFManager
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hwnd, out int pid);
        public static void Excel2Pdf(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
        {

            XlFixedFormatType targetType = XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF;
            object missing = Type.Missing;
            ApplicationClass application = null;
            Workbook workBook = null;
            int pid = 0;
            try
            {
                application = new ApplicationClass();
                object target = targetPath;
                object type = targetType;
                workBook = application.Workbooks.Open(sourcePath);
                workBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(targetType, target, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true, false);
                IntPtr ip = new IntPtr(application.Hwnd);
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(ip, out pid);
                //pid return 0 if run with IIS except ASP.NET Develop Server
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"D:\WebRoot\pid.txt", pid.ToString());
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
                p.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Urge well-wishers to help explain or give a solution code, thank you!

Comment: 1st piece of advice: Asking for code explicitly in your question is a good recipe for getting down-votes. 2nd: Call GetLastError() right after GetWindowThreadProcessId and let us know what it returns.

Comment: For debugging are you running it in IIS Express or the Visual Studio web server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does GetWindowThreadProcessId return 0 when called from w3wp.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024788/why-does-getwindowthreadprocessid-return-0-when-called-from-w3wp-exe)

Comment: @yms No error in this code,I tested.

Comment: @siva.k Yes,Running it with Visual Studio web server.

Comment: Did you see the answers on the other question that I referred? I think you are facing the same issue.